# Json mapper converts LocalDate to month, year, day of month etc

Tags: json, spring-mvc, jackson-databind, localdate

Json mapper converts  `LocalDate` to month, year, day of month ... when converting java class to json like this,

```
"dob":{
  "year": 1992,
  "month": "MARCH",
  "dayOfMonth": 19,
  "dayOfWeek": "THURSDAY",
  "era": "CE",
  "dayOfYear": 79,
  "leapYear": true,
  "monthValue": 3,
  "chronology": {
    "calendarType": "iso8601",
    "id": "ISO"
  }
}
```

this is saved as a `Date` in mysql as `1992-03-19` how to return this date as it is like

```
"dob:1992-03-19"
```

Comment: Just curious, how even it is possible to serialize LocalDate to the kind of object w/ a bunch of fields w/ Jackson Object Mapper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Jackson and `java.time` types

The Jackson [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) is used to handle [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) serialization and deserialization.

It provides a set of [serializers](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/ser/package-summary.html) and [deserializers](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/deser/package-summary.html) for the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types. If the [`SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) is *disabled*, [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types will be serialized in standard [ISO-8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) string representations.

### Handling serialization in your particular format

However, once you have a very *particular* format, you can create a custom serializer:

```java
public class DateOfBirthSerializer extends JsonSerializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(LocalDate value, JsonGenerator gen,
                          SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeString("dob:" + value.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE));
    }
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```java
public class Foo {

    @JsonSerialize(using = DateOfBirthSerializer.class)
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

Alternatively you can use:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(LocalDate.class, new DateOfBirthSerializer());

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

It will be applied to all [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) instances serialized with that [`ObjectMapper`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html).

### Handling deserialization in your particular format

For deserialization, you can use something like:

```java
public class DateOfBirthDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser p,
                                 DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {

        String value = p.getValueAsString();
        if (value.startsWith("dob:")) {
            value = value.substring(4);
        } else {
            throw ctxt.weirdStringException(value, 
                    LocalDate.class, "Value doesn't start with \"dob:\"");
        }

        return LocalDate.parse(value, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
    }
}
```

Comment: How to call or register this or where should i put this code so that the mapper can use this?

Comment: And that annotation tip, that is way too easy and most us prefer that